# Difference between lower sums and lower integral

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, riemann-sum

Why is it true that the lower sums of f with respect to some partition is less than the lower integral (which is the supremum of the lower sums)

I think what I'm confused about is the difference between a lower sum and the lower integral, how can the lower integral be the supremum of the lower sums when a lower sum is a single number?

Comment: You basically answered your question one the first sentence.

Comment: It is referring to a supremum of a set of lower sums given all possible partitions, not just the partition in question. The answer to your question is given by the definition of what a supremum is.

Comment: @DarrenNaylor oh so lower sums refers to a set of lower sums and so then the lower integral would refer to the smallest number in the set?

Comment: Not quite. The supremum is the least number that is greater or  equal to all the numbers in the set.